# UIScrollview doesn't work once subviews added

Tags: swift, scrollview

I'm new to working with ScrollViews, and I'm doing it all programatically.  I must be missing something super simple, but when I have no subviews, the scrollview shows up properly and scrolls up and down.  But any time I add any subviews, the whole thing refuses to show up at all.

```
class DetailedPostScrollView: UIScrollView {

let topLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "this is the top"
    return label
}()

let bottomLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "this is the bottom"
    return label
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    contentSize = CGSize(width: frame.width, height: 2000)
    alwaysBounceVertical = true

    addSubviewUsingAutoLayout(topLabel, bottomLabel)
    topLabel.centerXAnchor.constrain(to: self.centerXAnchor)
    topLabel.widthAnchor.constrain(to: 200)
    topLabel.heightAnchor.constrain(to: 50)
    topLabel.topAnchor.constrain(to: self.topAnchor, with: 100)

    bottomLabel.centerXAnchor.constrain(to: self.centerXAnchor)
    bottomLabel.widthAnchor.constrain(to: 200)
    bottomLabel.heightAnchor.constrain(to: 50)
    bottomLabel.bottomAnchor.constrain(to: self.bottomAnchor)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

And in my viewController, I instantiate and add the scroll view

```
let detailedPostScrollView = DetailedPostScrollView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    detailedPostScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    view.addSubviewUsingAutoLayout(detailedPostScrollView)
```

Again, I"m sure it's something super simple but I checked out all the questions and tutorial videos and couldn't see where I"m going wrong.  Thanks for your help.

Edit: It seems to work fine when I do it all programmatically from a viewcontroller, as follows :

```
 let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let sv = UIScrollView()
        sv.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 2000)
        sv.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
        return sv
    }()

    view.addSubviewUsingAutoLayout(scrollView)
    scrollView.topAnchor.constrain(to: view.topAnchor, with: 100)
    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constrain(to: view.leadingAnchor)
    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constrain(to: view.trailingAnchor)
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constrain(to: view.bottomAnchor)

    let topLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "this is the top"
        return label
    }()

    scrollView.addSubviewUsingAutoLayout(topLabel)
    topLabel.centerXAnchor.constrain(to: scrollView.centerXAnchor)
    topLabel.widthAnchor.constrain(to: 200)
    topLabel.heightAnchor.constrain(to: 50)
    topLabel.topAnchor.constrain(to: scrollView.topAnchor)
```

Something is off when I create a custom scrollview and instantiate that in my vc.

Comment: don't forget to set constrain is active = true and set the view translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Comment: Ah sorry forgot to mention I’ve added extensions so that it’s automatically active and turns off auto resizing, that’s not the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
class ViewController : UIViewController , UIScrollViewDelegate{
    var scrollView : UIScrollView! ;
    var containerView = UIView();
    var contentSize : CGSize {
        get {
            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 2000);
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        setupScrollView();
        setupItems();
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews();
        self.scrollView.frame = self.view.bounds;
        containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentSize.width, height: contentSize.height);
    }

    private func setupScrollView() {
        scrollView = UIScrollView();
        scrollView.delegate = self;
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .white;
        scrollView.contentSize = contentSize;
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView);

        containerView.backgroundColor = .purple;
        self.scrollView.addSubview(containerView);
    }
    private func setupItems() {
        let topButton = UIButton();
        topButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        topButton.setTitle("TOP BUTTON", for: .normal);
        topButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal);
        self.containerView.addSubview(topButton);

        let bottomTextField = UITextField();
        bottomTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        bottomTextField.borderStyle = .roundedRect;
        bottomTextField.placeholder = "BOTTOM TEXT FIELD";
        self.containerView.addSubview(bottomTextField);

        topButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true;
        topButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true;
        topButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true;
        topButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true;

        bottomTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true;
        bottomTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true;
        bottomTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true;
        bottomTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true;
    }

}
```

Set the scroll view frame to view bound in `viewDidLayoutViews` instead of using the layout , and add a container view as a subview for scroll view and set the size to same content size for scroll view again in `viewDidLayoutViews` so when ever user rotate the phone he get the correct width , and finally add all your views to container view .